# Wagtail models.py: How to create Custom folder in Media?

Tags: python, django, django-models, wagtail, wagtail-admin

- In [Wagtail](https://wagtail.io/), How to add custom folder in Media and sync it into the database ([Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZglX.png)) ?
- **NOTE:** The Wagtail's Collection function is good, but for more than 1000 images/documents into a single folder will be pretty awkward to manage for I in the future (Ex: migration,...), **so there is nothing to mention about Collection function in this question**.

```py
# If in Django (models.py) works:
class post(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts')
```

```py
# So how in Wagtail (models.py) works:
class Posts(models.Model):
    img = models.ForeignKey(
        "wagtailimages.Image",
         upload_to='posts', # How to add this line correctly ?
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=False,
        related_name="+",
    )
```

---

#### Idea for Media Folder in Wagtail:

- Media

  - authors

    - images
    - original_images
  - posts

    - images
    - original_images
      ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want specific folders for specific models, you can set a specific folder by customizing the `upload_to` attribute in the model. Otherwise, the only option I know is to create collections.